# Select every visible last child in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I would like to get the last **visible** `td` in each `tr` in a table.

This does not work because it attempts to select the last child *if* it is visible:

```
var last_visible_cells = $(table).find("tr td:visible:last-child");
```

So far the simplest method I've thought of is to use a `.each` to loop through the `tr` elements and append each of the last visible `td`s to a new selector list.

Is there a simpler way?  Does anything like this exist?

```
var last_visible_cells = $(table).find("tr").lastMatching("td:visible");
```

Comment: that first one also isn't valid syntax.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it:

```
$('table tr').find('td:visible:last').addClass('last-visible');
```

See a [full example](http://jsfiddle.net/4TSWb/) (jQuery 1.2+ compatible)

Answer (score 2):

to get every last visible them you can do something like

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('td:visible:last'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>You want to grab all the TDs and filter for only the ones that don't have a visible element next to it.</s>

Dang, that only works if there aren't any invisibles in the middle of the row.

Comment: If a group of <td> tags alternated in visibility (e.g. 0101010), selecting "all visible tags without a visible following tag" would select all visible tags, instead of only the last one. Instead, use nextUntil(). http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from Mathletics, but using `nextUntil()`. This finds each visible tag that doesn't have a following visible tag.

```
$('table tr').children('td').filter(function() { 
  return $(this).is(':visible') && $(this).nextUntil(':visible').length === 0; 
})
```