# How to select every last child which got specific css property?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select every last element which got `display:block` properties in a hidden parent element.

[**Here is an example fiddle to play with.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3h9CB/20/)

**html:**

```
<ul style="display:none;">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li><!-- my goal is find last visible child on every hidden ul -->
    <li style="display:none;">4</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    visibleCountOnEachUl =+ 0;
    $(this).children('li').each(function(index) {
        if ( $(this).css('display') === 'block' ) {
            visibleCountOnEachUl += 1;
            $(this).addClass('theseAreVisible');
            //this part works;
            //i can select elems elems which got display:block

            //but can't select the last elem on each ul
            //if ( index === (visibleCount-1) ) {
                //$(this).addClass('last-visible');
            //}
        }
    });
});

$('ul').find('li:visible:last').addClass('last-visible');
//This won't effect on child elements while their parent is hidden.
```

I found this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496592/select-every-visible-last-child-in-jquery) but solution works on visible parent.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? All children of a hidden parent will also be hidden, so I'm not sure that this approach is particularly reliable/useful.

Comment: @DavidThomas i am trying to count all children in each `ul` which got `display:block` property than find the last of it.

Comment: I get that, but what is it you're trying to do once you've got that last element? Why do you need to find it at all?

Comment: Its necessary on my project for defining different type of design on these elements @DavidThomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    $(this).children('li').each(function(index, elem) {
            var l = $(elem).parent().find('li').filter(function() {
                return $(this).css('display') === 'block';
            }).length;
            if (index == l-1)
                $(this).addClass('last-visible');
    });
});
```

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/H6Dbd/1/)

Comment: I am trying to find every last `li` which got `display:block` property? Is that make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sense, but that does'nt work when the parent is display `none`, as then all the children `li`'s will return display `none` as well -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3exZB/)

Comment: Check the `each` function carefully, it can select elements which got `display:block` property and only change their html values: http://jsfiddle.net/3h9CB/

Comment: @Barlas - Does this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3h9CB/4/) do what you want ???

Answer (score -1):

This will work when the parent is display:block:

```
$('ul li:visible:last').addClass('select');
```

When the parent is display:none, you should make the element positioned absolute, visibility: hidden or position them out of the viewport.

```
if( $('ul').css('display','none') ){

        $('ul').css({
            'display':'block',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'visibility': 'hidden'});

        $('ul li:visible:last').addClass('select');
    }
```